# Asp.net page life cycle - when does OnLoad event gets triggered .

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i am confused between different page life cycle events of asp.net. when does the onLoad event gets triggered. And on server side there is already a method called page_load. is this method part of page life cycle and when this method comes into picture

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: ASP.Net page life cycle overview is explained on MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load() method is called after a preLoad event.